# How to retrieve TextBox value on button click in side of asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
 <div class="row">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrProducts_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 ">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="background-color: white; width: 100%;">
                        <img src="images/<%# Eval("image")%>" class=" img" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" />
                        <div class="caption">
                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="hidden" ID="pid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productsID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="ProductName" style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold;">Title: <%#Eval("name")%></div>
                            <div class="ProductPrice" style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold;">Price: £<%# Eval("price", "{0:F2}")%></div>
                            <asp:Button ID="addItem" CommandName="addItem" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("productsID")%>' CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Add" OnClick="addItem_Click" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="quan" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this code which display my products. I am now trying to figure out how to single out the correct textbox, for instance know which textbox the user has entered text into. I apologise if this is really vague, please ask for more details if necessary. I have also provided a picture to make it more understandable. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to do:

First, include this in your code behind:

```
void rptrProducts_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {        
      var quantityTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("quan");
      int quantity = 0;
      if (!Int32.TryParse(quantityTextBox.Text, out quantity))
                //what do you want to do if the value is not an int? like if someone passes a text? up to you

      //from here on, the int variable quantity has the value collected from the textbox
}
```

Reference can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then, in your html:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrProducts_ItemDataBound" **OnItemCommand="rptrProducts_ItemCommand"**>
```

Comment: would it be helpful if i provided my code for onItemBound ?

Comment: not really... the var textbox is the text box you are looking for.

Comment: okay, for instance, my users are going to be inserting integers only, would line of code suffice to convert this into ant int value. where q is of type int. >> q = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text); and btw i'm looking for the quan textbox not pid.

Comment: yeah, I realised that, and changed to quan. Im going to put some code for you... thanks me later ;0)

Comment: nice one mate !

Comment: on a side note, instead of

<asp:TextBox CssClass="hidden" ID="pid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productsID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
you should use

<asp:HiddenField ID="pid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productsID")%>'></asp:HiddenField>

Comment: aah yeah, thats a good call !, btw the code you provided does not store the value correctly it still reads it as a value of 0..